# Auto-generating HTML file & trying to open it in IE sometimes shows a blank page

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, mfc

I have a somewhat strange behavior associated with Internet Explorer (IE). My goal is to generate a report as HTML markup and display it to a user via the web browser. (Since my software is used in our corporate environment and most of those have IE web browsers by default, I observed this issue only with IE.)

The software is written as an MFC dialog-based app, that is run daily (at 7:30 am) from a repeating task scheduler task. (The task is set up to run only when a user is logged on, which is all the time. It's a single user account system, and that user is never logged out. Those machines are also powered on all the time.)

Upon startup my software generates the HTML markup, saves it in a temp file and then has IE display it to the user. That's it. (The goal is basically to automate this report and display it on the screen when the person begins their day.)

So I used basically the following code:

```
TCHAR buffTempFldr[MAX_PATH] = {0};
::GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, buffTempFldr);
StringCchCat(buffTempFldr, MAX_PATH, L"Log Report.htm");

//strHtml = CStringA with HTML markup of report in 8-bit ASCII format

HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(buffTempFldr, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwcbWrtn;
    ::WriteFile(hFile, (BYTE *)strHtml.GetString(), strHtml.GetLength(), &dwcbWrtn, NULL);
    ::CloseHandle(hFile);

    BOOL bInitted = SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));

    //Show in Web Browser (IE by default)
    int nRetSH = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", buffTempFldr, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    if(nRetSH > 32)
    {
        //Success
    }

    if(!bInitted)
        CoUninitialize();
}
```

The issue is that this works most of the time, but then maybe 10% of the time a user gets just an empty (blank) HTML page. And only after they hit refresh the page shows the actual report.

Obviously this is confusing for the users, so I'm trying to see why this is happening?

PS. The computers that this is done on are running Windows 7 Professional, and IE v.11, with regularly installed updates.

Comment: Try `FlushFileBuffers()` before `CloseHandle()`.  Also, `"open"` should be `NULL` to execute the file's default verb, and `if(!bInitted)` should be `if(bInitted)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. I'm not sure why I chose `if(!bInitted)`. Brain-fart I guess ;) As for `FlushFileBuffers()` I thought `CloseHandle()` intrinsically does it. Otherwise all that OS caching would have no sense.

Comment: A quick update. Just implemented your suggestions and it worked for the first couple times. But then on a 3rd or 4th try I got an empty IE screen again. So only after I hit F5 the contents showed up. Hmm... I'm puzzled as to why? The only thing that's different from me testing it manually (without a schedule) is that the screen may be off & the screensaver might have been shown previously. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have gotten to the bottom of it.

This looks like a bug in the IE 11 rendering engine. (Interestingly enough, I ran it on a machine with IE 8 and it worked fine.) I discovered this by accident. When IE shows a blank page, if I just slightly resize its window, my HTML markup is then drawn in an instant. This also seems to happen only when I run my page thru IE with the screen being off in the power saving mode (although maybe running screensaver does it too -- I haven't gone all the way to test it.)

So at the moment I chose to use the following "hack" that wakes the screen before I call my ShellExecute method:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)-1);
::Sleep(500);

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, strSaveFileTo, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But I would **strongly** recommend against using it, since it creates a race condition, or in other words, there's no way of knowing what happens first, the screen being woken up or IE page being displayed.

As a working solution though one may consider using a different web browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox that won't have this issue.